# Flutter: Text widget align decimal point

Tags: flutter

I want to add numbers (including negatives) displayed in a column widget.
How to align them with respect to the decimal points?

Any other widget or tricks to align them?

https://ibb.co/d0MhyNV

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need convert number to string, and split string by decimal points, here is my demo code.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _numberItemWidget('1'),
            _numberItemWidget('2.1'),
            _numberItemWidget('100'),
            _numberItemWidget('1002.002'),
            _numberItemWidget('-1002.002'),
            _numberItemWidget('+2'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _numberItemWidget(String number) {
    final strList = number.split('.');
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text(strList[0], textAlign: TextAlign.right,),
        ),
        Text(strList.length > 1 ? '.' : ' '),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(strList.length > 1 ? strList[1] : ''),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**update**
separate the + from the number string, then use another Text to display

```
  Widget _numberItemWidget(String number) {
    final strList = number.split('.');
    final plus = strList[0].indexOf('+') == 0;
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
              children:[
                Text(plus ? '+' : ''),
                Spacer(),
                Text(plus ? strList[0].substring(1) : strList[0], textAlign: TextAlign.right,)
              ]
          ),
        ),
        Text(strList.length > 1 ? '.' : ' '),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(strList.length > 1 ? strList[1] : ''),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I looking for.  For improvement, how to make the plus sign from the last item '+2' to be on the left of the leftmost digit? [link] (https://ibb.co/n75CRCD)

Comment: @DollyStorey i just updated my answer, pls check that

Answer (score 0):

To align numbers, including negatives, with respect to the decimal points in a column widget, you can use the `Text` widget along with the `TextAlign` property. The `TextAlign` property allows you to control the horizontal alignment of the text within the widget.

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    Text('12.34'), // Example positive number
    Text('-56.78'), // Example negative number
    Text('90'), // Example whole number
  ],
)
```

Keep in mind that this approach will align the numbers based on the decimal points. If you have numbers with varying decimal places, the decimal points will be aligned, but the whole numbers may not be perfectly aligned

Example using the `Table` widget:

```
Table(
  children: [
    TableRow(
      children: [
        TableCell(
          child: Text('12.34', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    TableRow(
      children: [
        TableCell(
          child: Text('-56.78', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    TableRow(
      children: [
        TableCell(
          child: Text('90', textAlign: TextAlign.end),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```